# Copy values into a different data frame in R

Tags: r, csv, copy

I have the number of likes for each specific user in one csv file and I want to copy them into another csv file using R which has a list of users in a different order.

```
File 1     ------->    File 2

user  likes            user   likes
A     20               A
B     15               B
D     30               C
E     7                D
H     19               E
                       F
                       G
                       H
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is easy: read in the data, reorder it using `order` and write it to file using `write.csv`.

```
f1 <- read.csv('file1.csv')
write.csv(f1[order(f1$user),],'file2.csv')
```

In the future, though, remember to show the code you've already tried so we know where you're starting from.